# file opening pointer

Tags: c, linux

I want to ask that in c programming we open a file using pointer by using how many pointer at the same time we can open the same file with out getting any error? Is there a limit? Also does sequence matter like

```
f1= fopen("abc.txt",r)
f2= fopen("abc.txt",w)
```

do f2 be close first or f1 can be close first too

Comment: try it by yourself, then tell us..

Comment: If you have declarations equivalent to `static const char r[] = "r";` and `static const char w[] = "w";`, then what you wrote will work.  Most commonly, though, people write `FILE *f1 = fopen("abc.txt", "r");` etc.  The semi-colons are mandatory.  (And the compiler will be even stroppier about this than I am.)

Comment: You can close the file streams in any order, independently of the order in which you open them.  However, if you have multiple write file streams, and you write different data to the different streams, the order in which you close the streams may impact the data that appears.  So, too, will the order in which the standard I/O code flushes buffers to disk.  And some systems may impose limits on the number of simultaneous writers to a single file (like one at a time) - it appears to me that Windows can control things so that only one process is modifying a file at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most standard libraries impose some limit on how many files a particular process can have open at a time. As long as you're halfway reasonable about things, however, and only open files as you need them, and close them when you're done, it's rarely an issue.

You're guaranteed that you can open at least `FOPEN_MAX` files simultaneously. In some cases you can open more than that, but (absent limits imposed elsewhere, such as the OS being short of resources) you can open that many.

Edit: As to why you can often open *many* more files than `FOPEN_MAX` indicates: it's pretty simple: to guarantee the ability to open N files, you pretty much need to pre-allocate all the space you're going to use for those files (e.g., a buffer for each). Since most programs never open more than a few files at a time anyway, they try to keep that number *fairly* low to keep from wasting too much memory on space most don't use anyway.

Then, to accommodate programs that need to open more files, they can/will use realloc (or something similar) to try to allocate more space as needed. Since realloc can fail, though, the attempt at opening more files can also fail.

Comment: A question about this: FOPEN_MAX is 16 on my system, which surprised me, being so low, and when I tried just now I could fopen 1021 files. Why such a large discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the answer for your system. I got 16 on mine, FWIW.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", FOPEN_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```